# How to use an aar including other aar in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, azure, xamarin, binding, aar

I'm developing an APP using Xamarin, which needs to use other aar developed by Android Studio (AS).

In AS, I created a Java Library module named like "javaLib". After built, I got javaLib-debug.aar. Then I created a Bindings Library (Android) project and added this aar. After built, I got AarBinding.dll.

In Xamarin.Android, I added this dll as a reference and can use it normally.

But now in my aar, I need the support of other libraries, for example, azure-storage-android. 
To do that, in my module's build.gradle, I added,

compile 'com.microsoft.azure.android:azure-storage-android:0.7.0@aar'

Then I can use Azure APIs in my module and it works well in the APP generated by AS.

But when I use the dll including Azure APIs in Xamarin.Android, other part of this dll still works, but Azure APIs don't. It seems they don't run.

Is there a way to use an aar including other aar in Xamarin.Android? How to achieve that? Any examples and suggestions are appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to use an aar including other aar in Xamarin.Android? How to achieve that? Any examples and suggestions are appreciated.

Refering to [Troubleshooting Bindings](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/troubleshooting-bindings/):

> The external dependencies for the library – Any Java dependencies required by the Android library must be included in the Xamarin.Android project as a ReferenceJar or as an EmbeddedReferenceJar.

So, you need to find the azure-storage sdk lib and copy it into your project as `ReferenceJar` or as `EmbeddedReferenceJar`.